# Batch Script Issue

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, find

Hi I'm new to scripting 
i created this sample script to filter out all the timestamp from a log file 
when i use this manually in cmd prompt it works for me but the same doesn't work in a .bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF  

: ************** Report Tracking in FR *************************************************
: ********** to find keywords relevent Timestamps **************************************
: ****************** From the Log files ************************************************

cd F:\oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\EPMSystem\servers\FinancialReporting0\logs
(FOR %G IN (*.log) do (find /i "Name:" "%G"))> out.log
```

any idea as to what i might be missing

Comment: Hi Stephan, 
But change worked but now the cmd is jumping on to the directory where my script resides and doesn't execute the cmd  

    (FOR %%G IN (*.log) do (find /i "Name:" "%%G"))> out.log

 

in the desired folder 

    F:\oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\EPMSystem\servers\FinancialReporting0\logs


Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: `cd /d "F:\oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\EPMSystem\servers\FinancialReporting0\logs"`  <--- try that format of the command.

Comment: Thank you foxidrive. @user3124129 I get a message if you comment to my answer or if you explicitely write `@Stephan`; I don't get a message, if you comment to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Problem:

```
 (FOR %G IN (*.log) do (find /i "Name:" "%G"))> out.log
```

In Batchfiles you have to double the percent-sign for the "FOR-variable:

```
(FOR %%G IN (*.log) do (find /i "Name:" "%%G"))> out.log
```

Also if you try to change to another drive use `cd /d`

Comment: Thank you I'm new to this community.. This is GOLD! I hope i can learn a lot and contribute like you!